# django global variable

Tags: python, django, django-views

In views.py

When I try this one to access a global variable from other `def`:

```
def start(request):
    global num
    num=5
    return HttpResponse("num= %d" %num) # returns 5 no problem....

def other(request):
    num=num+1
    return HttpResponse("num= %d" %num)
```

`def other`  does not return 6, but it should be 6 right ? How can I access a variable globally in my view ?

Comment: add `global num` in all the functions where you want to use `num` from global scope

Comment: You can do it as explained in the answers or you could add the variable data into database and use that data globally.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/). This is exactly what they are designed for.

```
def foo(request):
   num = request.session.get('num')
   if num is None:
      num = 1
   request.session['num'] = num
   return render(request,'foo.html')

def anotherfoo(request):
   num = request.session.get('num')
   # and so on, and so on
```

If the session has expired, or `num` did not exist in the session (was not set) then `request.session.get('num')` will return `None`.  If you want to give `num` a default value, then you can do this `request.session.get('num',5)` - now if `num` wasn't set in the session, it will default to `5`. Of course when you do that, you don't need the `if num is None` check.

Comment: Good answer, sessions are probably what he needs. You could just do `num = request.session.get('num', 1)` and remove the next two lines.

Comment: But the session can be cleared from client-side right?!

Comment: + It needs to be JSON serializable (`TypeError: Object of type 'XyGlobals' is not JSON serializable`)

Answer (score 9):

You could declare num outside one of the functions.

```
num = 0
GLOBAL_Entry = None

def start(request):
    global num, GLOBAL_Entry
    num = 5
    GLOBAL_Entry = Entry.objects.filter(id = 3)
    return HttpResponse("num= %d" %num) # returns 5 no problem....

def other(request):
    global num
    num = num + 1
    // do something with GLOBAL_Entry
    return HttpResponse("num= %d" %num)
```

You only need to use the global keyword if you are assigning to a variable, which is why you don't need `global GLOBAL_Entry` in the second function.

Comment: This is right for an int value, what if I have a query in a function and I want to use it globally. For example 'GLOBAL_Entry=Entry.objects.filter(id = 3)' How to declare 'GLOBAL_Entry'

Comment: the error says name 'null' is not defined, are you sure about null part ?

Comment: Oops, I meant `None`. Wrong language.

Comment: Will it work when Django executed from multi-thread `uwsgi` ? For exaple `start` will be called from one thread, and `other` from another

Answer (score 3):

You can open settings.py and add your variable and value.
In your source code, just add these line

```
from django.conf import settings
print settings.mysetting_here
```

Now you can access your variable globally for all project.
Try this, it works for me.

Comment: settings is only applicable for _simple_ types (like string, int) - JSON will not work

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this by using **global** keyword in **other()** method like this:

```
def other(request):
   global num
   num = num+1
   return HttpResponse("num= %d" %num)
```

now It will return 6. It means wherever you want to use global variable, you should use **global** keyword to use that.